# Appending google Analytics tracking code to existing GA code

Tags: google-analytics

i have the following GA code added to my website

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-67265472-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I created a different property to filter my own ip address from being tracked in Google analytics. The only difference in the tracking code is the below

```
ga('create', 'UA-67265472-2', 'auto');
```

Can i simply append this code to the end of the existing GA code or would i need to copy the entire new tracking code into the webpage.

Thanks in advance for your replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to include the part that loads the analytics.js file multile times.

However if you simply call `create` with a different account id a second time you will overwrite the existing tracker and all call will be logged to the second account id.

If you need multiple trackers per page you need to create a named tracker, and send a second pageview call (and events etc.) there:

```
ga('create', 'UA-67265472-2', 'auto' , 'myTrackerName');
ga('myTrackerName.send', 'pageview');
```

You can this after your existing code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

// default tracker
ga('create', 'UA-67265472-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

// custom name
ga('create', 'UA-67265472-2', 'auto' , 'myTrackerName');
ga('myTrackerName.send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: When you say 'myTrackerName' you mean the property name or do i simply add any name there?

Comment: You choose the name yourself, it does not have to be the property name.

Answer (score -2):

To add to the contribution of Eike Pierstorff. When using multiple trackers, it is recommended to start using Google Tag Manager. This will make tracking with multiple trackers much easier.

Especially when you want to track events, custom dimensions, virtual pageviews, ecommerce, etc.